# C# Windows Forms totally, completely, utterly disable Windows scaling anything

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

This looks like a duplicate question but other answers are generally "it's best practice to have Windows to re-scale your window items, here's how to do that" or "if you don't have Windows scaling your window elements here's how you can scale your items yourself". I do NOT want to scale anything in my C# Windows Forms application, i.e. the main window is a certain pixel size, the fonts should be a certain pixel size, and the placement of the elements should remain at the same pixel positions inside the main window.

I'm assuming this is difficult to do in Windows Forms, otherwise SO would have some succinct simple answer how to do it, but can anyone provide a simple example preferably in C#? The minimum outcome would include all the fonts staying the same size in pixels. An answer "make your app DPI aware" is unfortunately too vague for me to implement, although I've tried.

I know this means the application window will be half the physical size (but the same number of pixels) on a 4K 20" screen than a 1080p 20" screen, but that's exactly what I need.

Comment: Have you tried with a test Form, setting `AutoScaleMode = None` (the same with all other ContainerControls)? The DpiAwareness mode should be set to `PerMonitorV2` -- You didn't specify the .NET version you're targeting, or the supported System versions